# The method getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(int resid) doesn't work outside of onCreate()

Tags: android

Here is a short sketch of my application

```
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);

    ... //at this place, getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(int resid)
        //would work perfectly

    mainView();

}

void mainView() {
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   ...

   if (...) {
     getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.anyDrawable);
   }

   ...

}
```

But in mainView() that method doesn't effect anything. And no Exception is thrown out.

main.xml already defines a background image, but start.xml doesn't do it. Could this cause my problem?

Or can I change the background image in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PS you can't set the content view more then once, what you should be doing is in the layout have the parent view with an ID like main and then use

```
findViewById(R.id.main).setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.anyDrawable);
```

and in the xml layout you need to set the id of the view you want to set (this should be the top most view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dip" 
    android:id="@+id/main"></LinearLayout>
```

Once you have added the id to the view you need to save the layout and build the project

If you want to post your xml code and also the name of your layout I can write more for you

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Android beginner and don't know how to match an ID to the layout. Would you like to help me with a very short code example?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly! (I only had to add a "@+id/" before the "main" in the xml file, but that was really not a problem...)

Comment: No problem, when someone gives you a correct answer you should accept the answer by clicking the tick next to the answer, and also upvoting the question if you think its worth it, you can do that by pressing the up arrow

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't notice the tick ... thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it took me a while to notice, other so users to appreciate for you to just click a tick for there work, or/and upvoting the answer